# QSignalSpy: Crash in wait()

Tags: c++, qt, googletest

I try to test my OPC UA connection, but my test crashes in the wait function of connectedSpy. The funtion `opcua->connect()` connects the client to the specified endpoint.

EDIT: The class OpcUa is part of a dll.

```
using namespace ::testing;
const QString END_POINT = "opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:43344";

class TestOpcUa : public Test
{
public:
    TestOpcUa()
    {
        testing::Mock::AllowLeak(_selectedConf);
        ON_CALL(*_selectedConf, getSERVERNAME()).WillByDefault(Return(END_POINT));
        _opcUaObject = new OpcUa(_selectedConf);
    }
    ~TestOpcUa() {}

protected:
    MockOpcConf* _selectedConf = new MockOpcConf();
    OpcUa* _opcUaObject = nullptr;
};

TEST_F(TestOpcUa, OpcUaConnectValid1)
{
    QSignalSpy connectedSpy(_opcUaObjectValid->getOpcUaClient(), &QOpcUaClient::connected);
    _opcUaObjectValid->getOpcUaClient()->connectToEndpoint(END_POINT_VALID); //works
    QVERIFY(connectedSpy.wait());
    ASSERT_EQ(connectedSpy.count(), 1);
    ASSERT_EQ(_opcUaObjectValid->getOpcUaClient()->state(), QOpcUaClient::Connected);
}

TEST_F(TestOpcUa, OpcUaConnectValid2)
{
    QSignalSpy connectedSpy(_opcUaObject->getOpcUaClient(), &QOpcUaClient::connected);
    _opcUaObject->connect(); //dont't work
    QVERIFY(connectedSpy.wait());
    ASSERT_EQ(connectedSpy.count(), 1);
    ASSERT_EQ(_opcUaObject->getOpcUaClient()->state(), QOpcUaClient::Connected);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

EDIT: I found the mistake, but I don't understand it. In `_opcUaObject->connect()` I create a new connect to a funtion in OpcUa. 
`QObject::connect(_client, &QOpcUaClient::stateChanged, this, &OpcUa::checkClientConnection);`
Why is that not allowed?

Comment: I do not see any Qt event loop in there. Is there anything else im your code? I think Qt needs you to create one before dealing with signals and slots

Comment: To answer this is basically to reply on "how to use Qt?" so I will limit this to comment.
`opcua->connect()` goes above `exec()` below
`qApp->exec()` is needed instead of `qApp->processEvents()`
`qApp->processEvents()` is to process current events in the queue only.
`connectedSpy.wait()` needs to be injected at some event in `qApp->exec()` or maybe instead of it as it is an event loop as well.

Comment: @AlexanderV I have edited my code. It still does not work. `qApp->exec()` starts a endless loop.